# Logo not running in my emulator and devices

Tags: react-native, expo

11:01:29: Failed building JavaScript bundle
11:01:29: Unable to resolve ./app/img/grangologo.png" from ".//App.js`: could not resolve`/home/gokul/React/Grango/app/img/grangologo.png' as a file nor as a folder","name":"UnableToResolveError","type":"UnableToResolveError","errors":[{}]},"type":"bundling_error"}"

Comment: You should be using [relative paths](https://www.w3schools.com/hTml/html_filepaths.asp) for all of your file access as a general rule of thumb (would be good to see some code though)

Answer (score 0):

you'r path to the image is wrong, try to use some `console.log`'s to check yourself if the image was imported.

(p.s you could avoid all of it by using proper editor)

Comment: vsc supposed to show you a red mark about it, show us some code so we will be able to help you more ...